# PHP Issue displaying (echo) JSON object items

Tags: php, json

I have a PHP file which is displaying some posted data:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');

echo json_encode($data);
```

The above returns:

```
{"name":"mark","item":"car"}
```

Now I want to echo just the name so I tried:

```
echo $data[0].name;
```

But that's giving me `Error: [Object].[Object]`

How can I fix this?

Comment: $data->name       15 chars in length for a comment. fgot

Comment: Sorry but that's returning Null

Comment: `echo $data['name']` will outputs `mark`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decode your JSON input first:

```
// $data is an input string    
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');

// convert input string to PHP array    
$data = json_decode(data, true);

// echo just the name
echo $data['name'];

// dump the whole parsed input
var_dump($data);
```